# Hi, I have sitution where my Database has corrupted but some how we have recovered it but while restoring the .bak file it shows an error

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, recovery, corruption

[image]

this is the error show while restoring the corrupted file .. Pls help if any one know
Thanks

Comment: Go ahead run `dbcc checkdb('db_name') with NO_infomsgs, all_errormsgs)` on database you just recovered from failure and tell me the result, as per the error message the backup is not consistent

Comment: Probably the backup is corrupted as well. It looks like it's in the system drive, where the data file is probably sitting as well. Possible disk failure?

Comment: Is there any possible way to restore the bak file again to the new server ?

Comment: Try adding `continue_after_error` clause while restoring. See if you succeed.

Comment: Still i get the same message as , Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The media family on device 'D:\DB\NASH_20160718.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Read the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037682/restore-db-error-restore-headeronly-is-terminating-abnormally Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the backup file is corrupt (something happened after a successful backup to break the file), incorrectly formed (possibly caused by a backup that failed mid way), or possibly not even a SQL Server backup (someone just named the file with a BAK extension).

When attempting to restore a backup from Management Studio Studio, SSMS uses the RESTORE HEADERONLY command before it actually restores the database. This step is the step that is being reported as failing in your error message.

This tells us two important things:

1. The operation fails *prior to* the actual restore.
2. At minimum, the backup header is corrupt or missing, but possibly more.

The header tells SQL Server information about this backup, as well as the database from which this backup was created. Without this information, the backup cannot be restored.

Your best bet is to move on to an older backup and attempt to restore that. If you have no good backups, then you're pretty much out of luck.